# Is there a way to make certain apps switch to my active screen? (Rather than other way)

Tags: macos, finder

I use a lot of screens, and each screen I have dedicated to a specific task, generally. What happens is that I have some apps, like Finder and Terminal, that I want to follow me when I switch to them. So my dream workflow would be like follows:
I'm working on a project. I need to grab a quick file or run a quick terminal command, I cmd-tab those apps and they come to my current screen so I can run a command or drag and drop a file.

I use iTerm with a transparent full screen setup, which is soooo cool when it overlays my current screen, but usually it just drags me to a different screen. I went through iTerm's settings (and Finder's) but it didn't seem like they had built in support for this sort of thing. Is there any MacOS trickery I can use instead?

I'm on OS El Capitan 10.11.06 but I can upgrade if that'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bring an app to the Space you're on in a single command.

You could use one of two workarounds...

1. Switch to the app, then grab its window title bar & switch back to the Space you wanted - the app will follow you.
2. Right click the app in the Dock & select Options > All Desktops.
   The app will then always be on the current Space.

Comment: Second one worked well for finder! Didn't work for terminal but that might be something in my settings, I'll go dig deeper